# Docker - Executed failed running "make install"

Tags: docker, dockerfile

All,

Got a question, trying to pull a repo and then use "make install" but get the error:

[image]

Can you tell me where do I go wrong?

My Dockerfile:

```
# For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM python:3.8-alpine

EXPOSE 5000

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache bash git openssh make

# TA-Lib
RUN git clone https://github.com/slegaitis/ta-lib.git ta-lib
RUN cd ta-lib/ && ./configure --prefix=/usr && make && make install
# End TA-LIB INSTALL

# Install pip requirements
# COPY requirements.txt .
# RUN pip install --upgrade pip && python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000", "app:app"]
```

Comment: `./configure` not found. Maybe you're in the wrong directory, or there is no configure script...

Comment: Even if i remove it get the error :/

Comment: I think its something to do with "make" either it doesn't find it or it doesn't install properly

Comment: Take a look into the code... You probably want to be in directory `ta-lib/c/` and run Make there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code at https://github.com/slegaitis/ta-lib doesn't have a `configure` script in the root folder.

Comment: You are right, thanks my own bad... :)